# Button resize problem. Android

Tags: android

in my project i have a view with 4 buttons. I have a relative layout to place them correctly. The thing is that i want the buttons to fill the whole screen without disappearing and I don't want to set a fixed size to them to ensure that the buttons will fit in any screen size. Right now the only thing i can see is one big button because RelativeLayout has no `android:layout_weight`. How can i accomplish this? Here's what i got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <Button
                android:id="@+id/search_icon"
                android:background="@drawable/search_icon"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                />

          <Button
                android:id="@+id/categories_icon"
                android:background="@drawable/categories"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/search_icon"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                />

          <Button
                android:id="@+id/green_icon"
                android:background="@drawable/green_icon"
                android:layout_below="@+id/search_icon"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                />

          <Button
                android:id="@+id/red_icon"
                android:background="@drawable/red_icon"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/green_icon"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems easier than I thought... I think you are looking for this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/button2" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button android:id="@+id/button3" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/button4" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Try it out, it should look like this:

[image: Android screen with 4 buttons]

Comment: Nice, it worked, what was the trick? The icons got deformed but i guess i should get the screen size and place the icons programmatically, ain't that right? Thanks for the answer!!

Comment: There was no trick, just trial and error... Android interfaces are a bit tricky, and sometimes you just have to test various Layouts to see the best one.
About icons, I can't help you... I still haven't used any. But, just like layouts, you get there with trial and error.

Comment: Alright, thanks for taking time to help. I really appreciate it. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?
[image]

Here is the code I did for this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
      <Button
            android:text="BUTTON 1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

      <Button
            android:text="BUTTON 2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/search_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
      <Button
            android:text="BUTTON 3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

      <Button
            android:text="BUTTON 4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you set everything on fill_parent then the whole screen will have just 4 buttons over it. This is an answer to the above question.

Comment: everything is set to fill parent. i can only see the 2 first buttons

Comment: it works if i don't set an image as background in the button. Otherwise i can only see the two first buttons

Comment: Just to get it straight...so, you have the four buttons taking up the entire screen, then adding the android:background attribute to each image only shows the first two buttons?

Comment: Yes, i set a background to the four buttons, because i want to set an icon to the buttons for a better look. I can only see two buttons when i set the image as a background for the buttons. But if there's no icon it works.

Comment: Hmm...try changing them all to ImageButtons?  I don't know why that would affect it thought :-\

Answer (score 0):

The thing about RelativeLayout is that you have to tell where to put the itens. Example:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/buyTicket" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Buy ticket"
    android:layout_above="@id/LinearLayout02" />

<ImageView android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/buyTicket" />
```

Pay attention to android:layout_above="@id/buyTicket".
If you want button A on top of button B, you first declare button A (for example), align it to top of parent, and then at the button B declaration, you say you want it under button A.

In your case, you have to declare button A, B, C and D, then set `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` in button A, and then set `android:layout_bellow` on B, C and D (to the one before them). And don't forget to set height and width to `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0):

Read this guy's blog if you have any of these problems: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/

Lots of examples, and explains things like weight really well.